# How to use a custom function in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have been looking for sliding in different directions via jquery . I have found a custom function in stackoverflow . But I don't know how to use it .

```
$.fn.fadeSlideRight = function(speed,fn) {
return $(this).animate({
    'opacity' : 1,
    'width' : '750px'
},speed || 400, function() {
    $.isFunction(fn) && fn.call(this);
});
```

}

Please tell me where to paste it and how to use it. Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to place it before you use it (probably near the beginning of your script) and can call it like so:

```js
$.fn.fadeSlideRight = function(speed,fn) {
  return $(this).animate({
    'opacity' : 1,
    'width' : '750px'
  },speed || 400, function() {
    $.isFunction(fn) && fn.call(this);
  });
};

$("#test").fadeSlideRight(500,function(){
    alert("fadeSlideRight callback");
  });
```

```css
#test{
  opacity:0;
  width:100px;
  background-color:red;
  height:50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">test</div>
```

Comment: it's working well when I press "Run code snippet " . but it doesn't when I do in my pc

Comment: @M.Rashid could you post your code of how you're using it? Including the CSS of the element you're trying to using it on and the actual function call on that element.  and are there any errors in the console?

Comment: i just broke down your codes into pieces and paste them into external css and script page but that failed . But the script.js , style.css and the jquery library is loading . But the function is not working

Comment: Can you give me any solution to slide divs into different directions such as to top , left right . It would be more helpful

Comment: Are there any errors?  also you could try using [jQuery's sliding function](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/sliding/) for sliding up and down and for left and right you can use animate like it's used in this function you're trying to use

Comment: As far I know the slidUp() method closes a opened div . I want to unfold a div from bottom to top

Comment: sounds like animate is the way to go then